# How to make a text stand by the right side of an image using html and css

Tags: html, css

i need help to get the text to stand by the right side of the image on the same level i have this

```
<a class="following-row" href="index-2.html?pid=2306">
                    <img alt="Girls logo" src="photos/users/35257/resized/9fd79de3589edff68db18bb6141025c3.jpg">
                    <span class="following-row-text">Girls<span class="item-details"> · 78 followers</span></span>
                </a>
```

i cant get to have a correct set of css styling that give me what i want, please i need help.

thanks

Comment: Please share your code, so it's possible to help you :)

Comment: `img{float: left;}` or `img{vertical-align: top;}` ? not sure what you want

Comment: try to use float:right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div>
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://cdn.jssor.com/demos/img/icons/icon_chrome.png">
  <span style="">Girls · 78 followers</span>
</div>
```

> Check this snippet

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer based on comments.

```css
a.wrapper img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.wrapper span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.wrapper:hover img {
  margin: -1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
a.wrapper:hover span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a hre="#" class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://pipsum.com/100x100.jpg" alt="Image">
  <span>Girls · 78 followers</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please can i add a link to the div inside the div and style the link. i.e

<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://pipsum.com/100x100.jpg" alt="Image">
  <div>Girls - 78 followers</div>
</a>
</div>

Comment: @mcdavid - Yes it's possible, check the updated answer!